# get result from db when clicking on a link

Tags: php

I am trying to get results from database when clicking on a link.

Just think there is link called `students` on my page and when click on it now I want to get all students from db and need to display in separate page lets called it search.php.

I have a list of such links and need to get different results from clicking on each link.

My problem is how search.php page identify which link is click by users and then how to display result belong to clicked link.

can anybody pointed me with correct logic to this.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code, this isn't homeworkhelp.com

Comment: I tried making a like like this - `<a href="search.php?type=student">Student</a>` and checking it in search.php page

Answer (score 0):

You use $_GET[''] global.

change your search.php like this

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['type'];
?>
```